# How does one simplify (x^2 - 4)(x-3)?

Tags: factoring, algebra-precalculus

I am currently studying for my College Algebra final exam and one of the questions I have to do is the following:

```
x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x + 12
```

I was able to simplify down to this:

```
(x^2 - 4)(x-3)
```

My question is, can you simplify this further?
All the online math calculators seem to suggest that it isn't possible but I found that I could factor (x^2 - 4) to this:

```
(x-2)(x+2)
```

So, if I were to simplify the original problem fully, would it look like this:

```
[(x-2)(x+2)](x-3)
```

Or this:

```
(x^2 - 4)(x-3)
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $x^3-3x^\color{red}2$?

Comment: Yes, I will update that. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: $(x+c)(x-c)=x^2-c^2$ is the identity.  The left hand side is generally considered "More simplified" because it is factored.  its like saying, 2*3=6.  6 is written as a product of two "smaller" numbers in the same way that $(x+c)(x-c)$ is simpler than $x^2-c^2$ ,

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven So if I am understanding you, the first of the two would be considered more simplfied?

Comment: Yes.  If you can write your expression in terms of other expressions of lower degree (exponent), that is generally (not always) considered "more simplified"

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the solid answer @Eleven-Eleven
If you would like to add it as a formal response then I'd be more than happy to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Note that the square brackets in $[(x-2)(x+2)](x-3)$ are completely unnecessary. Multiplication of real polynomials is, after all, associative.